# Free set of forms, icons, styles, etc for web-based admin interfaces

Tags: user-interface

Is there any free set of forms, icons, styles, images, etc for building web-based admin interfaces? If yes, which is the best?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A particularly common choice is [Silk](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/). It's a very comprehensive free set. There's also the [Silk Companion 1](http://damieng.com/creative/icons/silk-companion-1-icons).

Answer (score 3):

[Tango icons](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) is a set of free-as-in-speech icons. It is covered under [CC Attribution Share Alike 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license, so it should be viable for commercial work.

Answer (score 2):

**[Icon Archive](http://www.iconarchive.com/) [image: http://www.iconarchive.com/static/images/ia/logo/logo.png]**

is one of the very best source for any kind of icons.

Comment: That server doesn't allow hotlinking. Unless they have them cached, people don't actually see the images you meant to show.

Comment: Thanks Sören, I go so often to that site I had them in my cache!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iconspedia.com/