# copyright free collection of resource images for Delphi menu items and toolbar buttons

Tags: delphi, image, icons, menuitem, toolbars

Every time I need to create a menu or toolbar with actions I end up collecting some images extracted from different application and hand tuning them with the image editor. This is time consuming and boring (eventhough I admit that might be a refreshing break in some ocasions).

Do you know of any collection of such images? I would like to have at least images for all the menu items in the menu templates. They must be copyright-free. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are the [silk icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) (and others from famfamfam). Those are not *copyright-free*, but I figure you meant they needed to be unencumbered, free-to-use, etc. (Truly copyright-free stuff will be very, very hard to find.) The silk ones just require acknowledgement somewhere, nothing else.

Answer (score 9):

@PA check this link.

my favorite [famfamfam](http://famfamfam.com/)

[image]

[image]

and these questions in SO

- [Where can one find free software icons / images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images)
- [Free set of forms, icons, styles, etc for web-based admin interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145565/free-set-of-forms-icons-styles-etc-for-web-based-admin-interfaces)

and so on.

Comment: thanks, that's just what I was looking for. I have accepted the answer from TJ.

Answer (score 5):

We use [IconExperience](http://www.iconexperience.com/) which is *royalty free*. You buy a licence for a company. They do two different libraries, one called [V-Collections](http://www.iconexperience.com/v_collections/) and the other [X-Collections](http://www.iconexperience.com/x_collections/). There are various sections within them, that you can buy separately, but for V-Collections its $379 at most and X-Collections its $289.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is almost impossible to get "copyright-free" glyphs. Even Open Source is not copyright-free!

But if more-or-less-free-for-use glyphs are ok, then you might give **[glyFX's free icons](http://www.glyfx.com/content/page/free.html)** a try.

Comment: Delphi comes with that set. See C:\Program Files\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Images\GlyFX

Comment: +1 Those are **nice** And they don't even seem to require any significant acknowledgement (http://www.glyfx.com/license-toolbar.html). One could claim the statement "...you may not claim that you created any part of this library" suggests you need to make a disclaimer on your own copyright window/page, but it seems really easy to comply with.

Comment: you're right, no really need copyright-free but royalty-free.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome has good icon sets and the licence is GPL.
http://art.gnome.org/themes/icon

Answer (score 3):

You can search on Web. There are many sites with icons; I use these:

- http://www.iconlet.com/
- http://www.iconfinder.net/
- http://icons-search.com/
- http://www.veryicon.com
- http://www.iconlook.com/
- http://www.iconspedia.com/

Surely there are more.
You can search icons by name or cathegory, search similar icons, icons by packages,...

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

A good website to track is [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) I keep the RSS feed on my iGoogle page as the regularly have articles along the lines of [50 Beautiful Free Icon Sets For Your Next Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/12/14/50-beautiful-free-icon-sets-for-your-next-design/).  They're a bit "graphic designery" if you get my drift but they do provide some really useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Fugue and Diagona](http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/) icon sets. Again, they're not copyright-free, but can be used in exchange for attribution.