# How To Use An Image As A Button In Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-xe2

As the title implies, I am trying to figure out how to use an image as a button in my delphi app.[image: Currently the buttons look like below]

I would like the buttons to look more like this more or less.

[image]

Are there any resources or tutorials that anyone could recommend on which component I would use for this and how to go about using it properly?/

Comment: An ImageList with png images and toolbar buttons or buttons with Images and ImageIndex properties assigned generally works fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can made it without external component with TSpeedButton

active flat property .

and use in glyph bitmap...

your bitmap must with alpha channel...

for example :
http://0777.ir/img/alpha.bmp

this bitmap have alpha channel...

you can see the channels in adobe photoshop.

Comment: Hi, is there a source for obtaining these images that you know of? I don't own or use photoshop.

Comment: @Gary You'll need to obtain the images for yourself. No programming there. You need a designer.

Comment: Yes this need to photoshop design work , now programming work

Comment: If you cannot afford Photoshop or a designer, you can do-it-yourself with Gimp.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking more along the lines of stock ready images in that format, something like iconfinder.com

Comment: @Gary - If it was pngs you were searching for you could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235226/copyright-free-collection-of-resource-images-for-delphi-menu-items-and-toolbar-b   With bmps, you'll constrain your search quite a bit. Then again, if you're determined, you can convert pngs to bitmaps with alpha channel f.i. with GIMP as Penguino mentioned.

Comment: Correction: alpha channel is not required. Delphi can re-create alpha channel for indexed (palettee-based) images, with tha rule that left-top pixel colour would be turned into transparent ones. That is how standard TBitBtn glyphs like OK/Cancel are done, they use Fuchsia they in the runtime is turned to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Delph TSpeedButton as already mentioned. To answer your question about stock images, there are some free image sets you might find appropriate here: 
   http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/delphi-16x16-speed-button-icon-bmp-1599703.html .   I have not tried them.  One of these might be what you need to get started.   Yes, there are other places to get the resources... google 16 x 16 Glyphs  or icons or images.  There used to be several free tools to design your own icons..one comes to mind Icon Edit ( http://www.bouffler.freeserve.co.uk/icon_edit.htm ), if you google, look for a shareware tool by the same name with a version number.   And there are numerous commercial products.